# How to get the memory state of SRAM on power up?

Tags: power, sram

I am working on IoT authentication using a [physically uncloneable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_unclonable_function) (PUF). I have read several articles which suggest that [SRAM PUF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Types_of_physical_unclonable_function#SRAM_PUF) can be used for that purpose. However, I want to know how can I read the SRAM memory state? Are there any existing implementations in C or C++ which can be used to retrieve the SRAM PUF fingerprint? If there are some libraries, can someone please point out those?

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: I am using MSP430FR5994

Comment: The MSP430FR5994 has 4kB of RAM that by default is allocated to the LEA module, so should not be touched by other code. To read it just define a pointer to the absolute address. https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/666424?MSP430FR5994-Can-I-combine-4kb-LEA-RAM-with-SRAM-into-a-single-8kb-block-of-RAM-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the SRAM content right at power up and try to do that in C or C++ you are going to have some trouble....particularly on an embedded type system....because some RAM content may be zeroed at startup and other parts may be used for initial stack content. There are also some high reliability embedded applications where ECC is used for the RAM and this needs to be initialized by writing, in its entirety, to make sure all the check bits are set properly before any of the RAM is read. A read with an invalid ECC check can result in system reset or error hang.

This memory zeroing is typically done inside the "startup code" that is the first thing to execute when the MCU comes out of reset and fetches its first execution address from the reset vector. "Startup code" is typically written in the native assembly language of the MCU for ease of coding at the "bare metal" level of processor resource access. There are also performance reasons for the use of the assembly language.

Startup code packages that come with various C/C++ tool sets are often complex code because the code will be highly parameterized with conditional directives to deal with a multitude of different possible hardware configurations. I mention this because you will have to deal with this based upon what I state in my next paragraph.

To be able to read the SRAM content right out of the reset vector at power on you are going to have to either modify the "startup code" or add a new layer of "bare metal" code between the reset vector and when the startup module takes control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101441/discussion-between-michael-karas-and-elliot-alderson).

Comment: @MichaelKaras If I decide to use assembly language to get the power-on state of the SRAM, are there any existing implementations which I can use? If not, how hard would it be to code as I do not have much experience in Assembly?

Comment: @Aisha - I think if you are going to be successful in a project as complex as extracting security keys from an SRAM PUF that comprehending something like the need to code in assembly language would be the least of your worries. I suggest getting some books that discuss the assembly language for your specific processor and setting out to learn this skill.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use just a portion of the SRAM you could read a section of RAM that is not part of the **static** data memory, because the static memory area is initialized by the C runtime routine before your `main` function begins. The static memory includes all variables that are declared outside of any function as well as those that are explicitly made static with the `static` attribute.

So, you should read a section of RAM that will be used for the heap (dynamically allocated memory) or for the stack (but not close to the initial stack pointer).

You should be able to look at the linker map tables to determine the appropriate ranges for your application.

Comment: Please see comment I posted to you under my answer.

Comment: @Michael Karas thanks for your detailed replies to my question. I want to add here that SRAM PUF is very sensitive to noise and environmental (die, temperature and power supply) fluctuations. These factors can result in an output bit flip.The research papers I have studied so far suggest to use repeated measurements to assess the stability of an SRAM PUF output bit and selectively use the most stable bits as the PUF output. From this, I concluded that for SRAM PUF one needs to use a sufficient portion of the SRAM.

Comment: One of the studies uses 512 Bytes of SRAM as a fingerprint to avoid systematic skew of SRAM cells and subsequently obtains 128 bits of output data.  The use of error correction techniques to get stable SRAM PUF output. I hope this helps in understanding what is needed for an SRAM PUF.